# Display AdMob Native ad via Jetpack compose. But the onAdImpression function is not being called

Tags: admob, android-jetpack-compose, native-ads

To display Native ads via Jetpack Compose. Here's an example of how to display a Native ad using Jetpack Compose:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdLoader
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView

@Composable
fun MyNativeAdView(adUnitId: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val nativeAdFlow = remember { mutableStateOf<NativeAd?>(null) }

    val adLoader = remember {
        AdLoader.Builder(context, adUnitId)
            .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                nativeAdFlow.value = nativeAd
            }
            .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                    println("AdmobNativeAd onAdFailedToLoad $p0")
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded()
                    println("AdmobNativeAd onAdLoaded")
                }

                override fun onAdImpression() {
                    super.onAdImpression()
                    println("AdmobNativeAd onAdImpression")
                    // FIXME Here is not being executed
                }
            })
            .build()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    })

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.native_ad_admob_medium, null) as NativeAdView
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        update = { adView ->
            // Find the view IDs defined in the XML layout file
            val adIconView = adView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ad_app_icon)
            val adHeadlineView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_headline)
            val adBodyView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_body)
            val adCallToActionView = adView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.ad_call_to_action)
            val adAdvertiserView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_flag)
            val adMediaView = adView.findViewById<MediaView>(R.id.ad_media)

            // Register the view IDs with the native ad view.
            adView.headlineView = adHeadlineView
            adView.bodyView = adBodyView
            adView.callToActionView = adCallToActionView
            adView.iconView = adIconView
            adView.advertiserView = adAdvertiserView
            adView.mediaView = adMediaView

            // Populate the native ad view.
            val nativeAd = nativeAdFlow.value
            nativeAd?.let {
                adIconView.setImageDrawable(nativeAd.icon?.drawable)
                adHeadlineView.text = nativeAd.headline
                adBodyView.text = nativeAd.body
                adCallToActionView.text = nativeAd.callToAction
                adAdvertiserView.text = nativeAd.advertiser

                adMediaView.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
                adMediaView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)

                // Register the native ad view with the native ad object.
                adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Use the MyNativeAdView Composable function in your UI by simply calling it in your UI hierarchy.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    MyNativeAdView("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
}
```

When the native ad is displayed, the onAdImpression function is not being called.
If now we switch the screen to the launcher screen and back right now. Then the onAdImpression function had been called!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a hacky way to solve this issue. You need to call `requestLayout` on the `AndroidComposeView`. What I am doing is to call these helper methods as the very last in the `update` part of the `AndroidView`.

```
private fun View.requestLayoutWithDelay(delayMillis: Long) {
    post {
        val t = parent.findAndroidComposeViewParent()
        if (t == null) {
            postDelayed(delayMillis) {
                val k = parent.findAndroidComposeViewParent()
                if (k != null) {
                    k.requestLayout()
                } else {
                    Log.i("TAG", "This should never happen")
                }
            }
        } else {
            t.requestLayout()
        }
    }
}

private fun ViewParent?.findAndroidComposeViewParent(): ViewParent? = when {
    this != null && this::class.java.simpleName == "AndroidComposeView" -> this
    this != null -> this.parent.findAndroidComposeViewParent()
    else -> null
}
```

Example usage applied on the code provided in the question:

```
...
adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
adView.requestLayoutWithDelay(400)
```

Comment: This exactly working like a charm. Bro, you have saved my day. Even if you set delay time to 200, it still works fine. Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KunjeshVirani Lately i run into errors when using 200ms. I had to rollback to 400 as for some devices lower delay was not long enough